# How to print a custom checkout field into email order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-notifications

I would like print my custom checkout field into all e-mail notification, like in screenshot below.

[image: order detail]

---

**What works so far**

- Add the field to the checkout
- Process the checkout
- Update the order meta with field value
- Display field value on the order edit page

**My question**

- How to add the custom checkout field into email order details (as seen in the screenshot)

---

Here is my code that I have used so far, how can I further adjust it?

```php
/* Add the field to the checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Imię i nazwisko osoby obdarowanej') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Podaj imię i nazwisko osoby obdarowanej'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'required'  => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}

/* Process the checkout */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Imię i nazwisko osoby obdarowanej</strong> jest wymaganym polem' ), 'error' );
}

/* Update the order meta with field value */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) );
    }
}

/* Display field value on the order edit page */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Imie i nazwisko obdarowanej').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'My Field', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1)** Change your code to this

```php
/* Add the field to the checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Imię i nazwisko osoby obdarowanej') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Podaj imię i nazwisko osoby obdarowanej'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'required'  => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';
}

/* Process the checkout */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Imię i nazwisko osoby obdarowanej</strong> jest wymaganym polem' ), 'error' );
}

/* Update the order meta with field value */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'my_custom_checkout_field_create_order', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_create_order( $order, $data ) {   
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_my_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ); // Order meta data
    }
}

/* Display field value on the order edit page */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order) {
    // Get meta
    $my_field = $order->get_meta( '_my_field' );

    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Imie i nazwisko obdarowanej').':</strong> ' . $my_field . '</p>';
}
```

---

**Step 2)** overwrite the following template file

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php
>
> This template can be overridden by copying it to
>   **yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php.**

**Add** the following code **under** line number **84**

```
$my_field = $order->get_meta( '_my_field' );
if ( isset( $my_field ) ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo 'Imie i nazwisko obdarowanej:'; ?></th>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo $my_field; ?></td>
    </tr>               
    <?php
}
```